# Quaternion division and hyperbolic tangent tanh

Tags: glsl, linear-algebra, quaternions, hyperbolic-function

Quaternion multiplication is well-defined, and is known to me as "Hamilton product":

```
// hamilton product
vec4 qmul(in vec4 q1, in vec4 q2) {
    return vec4(
        q1.w * q2.xyz + q2.w * q1.xyz - cross(q1.xyz, q2.xyz),
        q1.w*q2.w - dot(q1.xyz, q2.xyz)
    );
}
```

However, for implementing `qtanh()` quaternionic function, we need division. So far I've found this, and it is working OK. Could you help me to undestand, where does this comes from?

```
// division
// https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/boost/math/quaternion.hpp
vec4 qdiv(in vec4 q1, in vec4 q2) {
float denominator = dot(q2,q2);
return vec4( 
    vec3(
        -q1.w*q2.x+q1.x*q2.w-q1.y*q2.z+q1.z*q2.y,
        -q1.w*q2.y+q1.x*q2.z+q1.y*q2.w-q1.z*q2.x,
        -q1.w*q2.z-q1.x*q2.y+q1.y*q2.x+q1.z*q2.w
    ),
    q1.w*q2.w + dot(q1.xyz, q2.xyz)
) / denominator;
}
```

Also, as far as I am trying to implement tanh().. are you aware of more computationally vat, than dividing sinh and cosh? For reals I've used to use following formula:  `tanh(x)=-1+2/(1+exp(-x))`. And that involves only single exponential calculus, instead of two..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. Division

Dividing a quaternion named **p** by a quaternion named **q** is nothing more than multiplying **p** by [the reciprocal of **q**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Unit_quaternion).

This is equivalent to multiplying **p** by the conjugation of **q** (which [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Conjugation,_the_norm,_and_reciprocal) equals **a – bi – cj – dk**) and dividing the product by a scalar equalling **q** norm squared:

[image]

From here it`s obvious where that `denominator` part comes from:

[image]

Now let`s rearrange the terms in `vec3` sums for better readability:

```c
vec3(
    -q1.w*q2.x + q1.x*q2.w - (q1.y*q2.z - q1.z*q2.y),
    -q1.w*q2.y + q1.y*q2.w - (q1.z*q2.x - q1.x*q2.z),
    -q1.w*q2.z + q1.z*q2.w - (q1.x*q2.y - q1.y*q2.x)
)
```

And now it suddenly gets clear what`s going on:

```c
vec3(
    -q1.w * q2.x    +  q1.x   * q2.w  -  (q1.y*q2.z - q1.z*q2.y),
    -q1.w * q2.y    +  q1.y   * q2.w  -  (q1.z*q2.x - q1.x*q2.z),
    -q1.w * q2.z    +  q1.z   * q2.w  -  (q1.x*q2.y - q1.y*q2.x)
)

...

    -q1.w * q2.xyz  +  q1.xyz * q2.w  -  (cross(q1.xyz, q2.xyz))
```

So yeah, quaternion division is just the regular run-of-the-mill multiplication, with the multiplicand being a reciprocal. That`s where the minuses come from, see the definition above.

### 2. Hyperbolic tangent

First, the definitions. For each **q = a + bi + cj + dk = a + v̅**:

[image]

So, to get both **e<sup>q</sup>** and **e<sup>–q</sup>** you only need to compute the following values: **e<sup>a</sup>**, **||v̅||**, **sin(||v̅||)**, **cos(||v̅||)**.

To compute **e<sup>–q</sup>** you should take a reciprocal of **e<sup>a</sup>** and multiply it by the rest of the equation with signs inverted. That won`t take much time, for all the values it consists of have already been computed. One `exp()` call, as requested =)

Comment: Could a tanh be implemented with only one exp() call, eg, for reals I used tanh(x)==-1+2/(1+exp(-x))

Comment: Could I cheat and somehow lower its  computational complexity?

Comment: @xakepp35 Seems like yes, but the comment section is not very convenient to post the solution. Please amend your question and I\`ll add it to my answer.

Comment: Added to the end

Comment: @xakepp35 Done.

Comment: You're great, saved me a lot of brain cells! Have a nice day ;-)